# Immutable.js: How to find an object in an array by specify property value

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an array made by Immutable.js:

```
    var arr = Immutable.List.of(
        {
            id: 'id01',
            enable: true
        },
        {
            id: 'id02',
            enable: true
        },
        {
            id: 'id03',
            enable: true
        },
        {
            id: 'id04',
            enable: true
        }
    );
```

How can I find the object with `id: id03`? I want to update its `enable` value and get an new array

Comment: `Array#findIndex` and then Update the object @ found `index`..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First you need to [findIndex](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/findIndex), and then [update](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/update) your List.

```
const index = arr.findIndex(i => i.id === 'id03')
const newArr = arr.update(index, item => Object.assign({}, item, { enable: false }))
```

OR

```
const newArr = arr.update(
  arr.findIndex(i => i.id === 'id03'),
  item => Object.assign({}, item, { enable: false }) 
 )
```

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @caspg's answer, but if your array was completely `Immutable`, you could also write, using [`findIndex`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/findIndex) and [`setIn`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/setIn):

```
const updatedArr = arr.setIn([
  arr.findIndex(e => e.get('id') === 'id03'),
  'enable'
], false);
```

or even use [`updateIn`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/updateIn), if you ultimately need a more toggle-based solution.